# Configuring Grunt, Jasmine and RequireJS all together

Tags: requirejs, jasmine, gruntjs

I'm a complete noob with Jasmine and RequireJS so any help is appreciated.

We have the following directory structure

```
/assets
      /libs <- populated by Jam
      /scripts
/tests
```

I'm trying to setup Jasmine + Grunt + RequireJS to run my tests however I keep getting the following error, when I run my grunt task *grunt jasmine* I've reviewed the error on RequireJS site but in my view everything is in place.

```
Error: scripterror: Illegal path or script error: ['scripts/MyModule']
```

Here is my Jasmine setup in my *gruntfile.js*

```
jasmine: {
    src: 'assets/scripts/**/*.js',
    options: {
        specs: 'tests/*spec.js',
        template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
        templateOptions: {
            requireConfig: {
                baseUrl: '/assets',
                paths: {
                'jquery': 'libs/jquery/dist/jquery'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a dead simple test *spec* :)

```
require(['scripts/MyModule'], function (myModule) {
    'use strict';

    describe('A suite', function() {
        it('should pass this test', function() {
            expect(myModule).not.toBe(null);
        });
    });
});
```

RequireJS works fine in my project, here is the setup that I run for that...

```
<script>
var require =
{
    baseUrl: '/assets'
};
</script>
<script src="/assets/libs/require.js"></script>
```

Where am I going wrong, what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I got it running, had to make the following change in the Jasmine config in my *Gruntfile.js*

```
baseUrl: './assets/'
```

It needed to step one directory up.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. It's useful for future reference!

Comment: For posterity: `.` means current directory and `..` is up one directory. If you start a path with `/` it will go to root level. On the client side that means root url, on the server side the filesystem root path.

Answer (score 2):

When you specifiy Grunt Jasmine's to use `/assets` as your basePath, it will be looking in your absolute `/assets` path, that mean that you will be saying to grunt to look in you filesystem root path.